# Junit test gives null pointer due to Util returning a null

Tags: junit

I have  custom Validators on a request body object. One of the validation annotation tries to make a database call to fetch and validate if it is valid. I have unit test that test the controller method where I am facing NULL Pointer as the util returns null.

My service code is very similar to one mentioned in this link below. Please check solution 1 with util class. Do check this link please
https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/b1477964-1e89-4601-83ce-389ff3052cf2/y

My unit test throws null pointer exactly at retutn instance.*******():

Here the "instance" itself is null

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by using MockedStatic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).